# Code no longer providing any output in terminal

Tags: c

I have been working on a hangman game for my class which is due today and just now it decided to no longer provide any output from my code. If someone could please give it a look so I can go back to possibly submitting this assignment, I would be very appreciative. I dont know what changed specifically.

```
char **readWordList(char *, int *);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char **wordList;
    char inputFile[100];
    int count = 0;
    int i;

    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("You need to provide the word list file name.\n ");
        printf("Usage: $0 filename\n");
        return -1;
    }
    wordList = readWordList(argv[1], &count);  //function (target input[s], y placeholder var)
    if (wordList == NULL) {
        printf("Read word failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("fortnite");
    int a = 0;   //placeholder variables
    int b = 0;
    int c = 0;
    int v = 0;
    int g = 0;
    int hit = 0;
    srand(time(NULL)); //random variable for word selection
    int r = rand() % 3;
    int chances = 10;
    char *word = wordList[r]; //address word from line.txt
    char guess;
    char misses[10];
    int lettercount = 0;
    //make blank variable by reading random accessed word
    for (size_t a = 0; word[a] != 0; a++) {
        lettercount++;
    }

    char space[lettercount];
    // write underscores in place of spaces in temporary array
    for (size_t c = 0; word[c] != '\0'; c++) {
        space[c] = 95;
    }

    char blank[lettercount * 2]; //equal to array size empty array
    // borrowing my spacename function, but seems to make artifacts in blank input now
    int t = 0;
    int k = 0;
    while (space[t] != '\0') {
        k = 2 * t;
        if (k > lettercount * 2 - 2) {
            blank[k] = space[t];
            break;
        }
        blank[k] = space[t];
        blank[k + 1] = ' ';
    }

    while (chances > 0) {
        printf("Chances:%d\n", chances);
        printf("Misses:%d\n", misses);
        printf("Word:%s\n", blank);
        printf("Guess[Q]:");
        scanf("%c\n", &guess);
        while (word[b] != '\0') {
            if (guess = 'Q') {
                exit(0);
            }
            if (guess = word[b]) {
                v = b * 2;
                blank[v] = guess;
                b++;
                hit = 1;
            }
            b++;
        }
        if (hit != 1) {
            misses[g] = guess;
        }
        if (hit = 1) {
            hit = 0;
        }
        chances--;
        g++;
    }
}
```

Comment: At a guess, the strange creation of `spaces[]` is not null terminated... UB is when something works and then it doesn't... A previous version of teh executable had a fortunate NULL. Sounds like things have shifted, now, and your code walks off into space.

Comment: You say you fixed it, but I am skeptical that it works. All of those `if ... = ...` assignments (will be compiler warnings) don't appear intentional.

Comment: `printf("Word:%s\n",blank);` is bad as array `blank[]` is not a _string_.

Comment: `if (guess=word[b]){` is an assignment.  Is that intended?

Comment: `printf("Usage: $0 filename\n");` is NOT how one uses `argv[0]` to display the name of the program running... Not in C, at least...

Comment: Note that you will always pick the 0th, 1st, or 2nd word from `wordList`. If you are certain that there are 3 words or more, this will work, but if `count` stores the number of elements in `wordList`, you should probably be using `int r=rand()%count;` instead of `int r=rand()%3;`

Comment: Index variable `b` starts with value 0... That is good... If the rest of the code actually worked, it's value would only increment. You might want to reset it to 0 before entering the evaluation loop for each 'chance'.

Comment: I avoid it, so I'm no expert, but the format specifier for `scanf()` to get each 'guess' looks like so many other SO questions, "Why doesn't this work?"... It's likely going to also be a problem for you. Perhaps there's another SO question in the offing..

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems in the code, including some serious ones:

- the `#include` lines are missing.
- the `readWordList` function is missing.
- `if (guess = 'Q')` sets `guess` to `'Q'` and evaluates to true. You should write `if (guess == 'Q')`
- `if (guess = word[b])`... same problem.
- `printf("Misses:%d\n", misses);` should be `printf("Misses:%s\n", misses);` and `misses` should be initialized as the empty string.
- `printf("Word:%s\n", blank);` has undefined behavior as `blank` is not null terminated.
- `while (space[t] != '\0')` may iterate too far as `space` does not have a null terminator since it's length is `lettercount` and all elements have been set to `95` ('_' in ASCII).  Yet since you never increment `t`, you actually have an infinite loop. Use a simple `for`  loop instead: `for (t = 0; i < lettercount; t++)`
- `scanf("%c\n", &guess);` reads a character and consumes any subsequent white space, so the user will have to type another non space character and a newline for `scanf()` to return. You should instead use `scanf(" %c", &guess);`
- `while (word[b] != '\0')` will iterate beyond the end of the array after the first guess because you do not reset `b` to `0` before this loop. Furthermore, `b` is incremented twice in case of a hit. You should use `for` loops to avoid such silly mistakes.
- `if (hit = 1) { hit = 0; }`... the test is incorrect (it should use `==`) and you could just write `hit = 0;` or better set `hit` to `0` before the inner loop.
- `inputFile` is unused.

You should compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror` to avoid such silly bugs that can waste precious time.

Comment: yeah sorry i couldnt get the readwordlist function to be in there as well due to the forum bot deeming it to be too heavy of code to post. thank you so much for the input, ill go over everything you covered. 

what does gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror do by the way? no need to comment if warranted, ill probably look them up by tomorrow evening. 

also thank you for the while(space[t]!='\0') explaination, i've been absolutely decimated by my comprehension of this process due to a low tier course education and only being able to utilize lab/real examples/applications this year.

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it, i lost a variable which provided the chance that a while loop would end for the spacing array function

sorry for being annoying

Comment: Code remains with many problems.

Comment: yeah :') i thought i did a good job but looking at some of y'all posts im really getting to understand how uneducated/disciplined i am at this. if it makes you feel better this will be my only programming course and will not be completely relevant to my future career.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).